# Creating a VirtualBox image from a physical Ubuntu Machine

Tags: boot, mount, virtualbox

I am trying to create a virtualbox image from a physical ununtu machine. I already have a raw image of the physical disk that I got using:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/f/disk.raw bs=1024
```

Then converted this image to VMDK using this command:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw /mnt/f/disk.raw /mnt/f/disk.vmdk --format VMDK
```

After that I created a new virtual machine in Virtual box. I choose "Linux" and "Ubuntu 64-bit" when creating the image then I choose the vmdk file that I created as the hard disk.

Now when I run the image I am getting this error: "No bootable Medium found!"

I made sure that it's using the hard disk to boot. Your help is much appreciated I have been stuck on this for a while now!

Comment: Perhaps the bootloader is missing. The bootloader is outside the partition that you copied.

Comment: @user535733 oh if that's the case I would be Fd! .. I no longer have the disk as it was formatted. Will there be any way to help in this situation?

Comment: You can try running boot repair. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ FYI, I've moved real-to-virtual several times, but I use Clonezilla. Clone the physical machine -> Restore the clone in VB.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't use clonezilla as I no longer have the physical machine. only the disk image that I got using dd

Comment: Try boot repair https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: You could also boot the VM using a LiveUSB .iso, then chroot into the VM and reinstall GRUB. Takes the tiniest amount of research to safely chroot and the correct commnd to reinstall GRUB.

Comment: thanks @user535733 I will try that